# How can I find the power provided by the battery?

Tags: power, bjt, npn, pnp, bias

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f00KUc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I find the power provided by the battery? I've calculated the operation point:

- Vce(Q1): 8.12V
- IC(Q1) = 1.63 mA
- Vec(Q2): 6.25V
- IC(Q2) = 4.4 mA

Is there another way instead of summing all the currents entering one of the nodes of the battery and then multiplying it by battery voltage?

Comment: John, I went ahead and just rotated Q2, so that the schematic is now less confusing. Also, happens to be pretty symmetrical. I hope that helps you analyze it :)

Comment: *Is there another way instead of summing all the currents entering one of the nodes of the battery and then multiplying it by battery voltage?* The definition of power delivered by the battery is \$P_{BAT} = V_{BAT}*I_{BAT}\$, there's no way around determining \$I_{BAT}\$ as far as I know and the way to determine \$I_{BAT}\$ is finding the DC solution of the circuit either by simulation or by hand. And indeed, R3 can't be 100 ohms if R4 is 22k. As it is, Q2 will be **off**

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I can’t edit that from my iPad but I’ll do it as soon as possible. The fact is that I am supposed to find the power in 3-4 minutes maximum (by hand), that’s why I was looking for a faster way...

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller it’s more readable now!

Comment: changed the 100 Ω to 4.7 kΩ for you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a way: go to DC simulation and add this expression:

`-I(BAT1.nA)*V(BAT1.nA)`

Comment: I know that would be easy, but I was looking for a "mathematical solution"

Comment: What makes a solution "mathematical"? Is \$V_{bat}\times(I(R_1)+I(R_5)+I(R_3))\$ (assuming the current directions through the resistors are defined appropriately) mathematical enough?

Comment: It's pretty impossible to precisely localize @ThePhoton; that would mean we'd lose all information about the impulse carried by The Photon, and that'd be bad.

Comment: @JohnBardeen "mathematical solution": Oh, so you have a closed-form description of the current through Q1 and Q2 given their operational point? And not just some formula that would be barely useful enough to put it into a simulation?